# Load cache data from excel with phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using phpexcel to open excel file. I am having a problem with it.

This is my excel 's file

[image]

We can see in it: cell H4 have function VLOOKUP, but it have link to another sheet. But at now link to C:... is wrong, and I want to get number 37512 (that is cache data because we can't recalculate that function now.). I tried to use with getCalculatedValue, but that function recalculate. How can I can get it?

Comment: Impossible to answer with this little amount of information, and without a real example to demonstrate the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answer automatic be generate. You can't load cache.